# Compact error checking

Tags: vba

Is there an elegant way to write an if A OR B OR C then X else do nothing statement? E.g.

```
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("J:J")) <> SymbolCount Then
    MsgBox "Check column J in Estate worksheet for fill completion"
End If
If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("K:K")) <> SymbolCount Then
    MsgBox "Check column K in Estate worksheet for fill completion"
End If
```

The most creative solution I could think of is to add the CountAs and see if it matches SymbolCount * NumberOfTests, but that would mean giving a non-specific response message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a try (if I understood well your question):

```
Sub test()
Dim SymbolCount As Integer, i As Integer
Dim aCols(2) As String
aCols(0) = "J"
aCols(1) = "K"

SymbolCount = 0
For i = 0 To UBound(aCols) - 1
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range(aCols(i) & ":" & aCols(i))) <> SymbolCount Then
        MsgBox "Check column " & aCols(i) & " in Estate worksheet for fill completion"
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```